# Android. How to get layout values from views in TabHost?

Tags: android, layout, android-tabhost

I have a TabHost hosting 3 Activities. In addition to the tabs, I want support for swipe gestures to change the current tab. My issue is that one of the views holds a horizontal scrollview, and I cannot figure out how to prevent touches in the horizontal scrollview from changing the current tab.

plateView is the horizontal scrollview that needs to be handled. Finding it's bottom with plateView.getBottom() and not counting touches above that works without the TabHost, but now it returns null and crashes, regardless of where it's called.

onTouchEvent counts touches everywhere and dispatchTouchEvent doesn't count touches on any widget. It seems some combination of them would be great, but together they yield the same functionality as onTouchEvent alone. Swipes anywhere count to change the Activity. My understanding of these is a little fuzzy though.

Why does getBottom() return null? How can I get this to work?

```
gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new CalcGestureDetector());
gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(TAG,"onTOUCH");
        if(gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)){
        return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

//Takes the touch and interprets it. Handles it. Changes tabs on fling.
class CalcGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener{
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent eOne, MotionEvent eTwo, float velocityX, float velocityY){
        Log.d(TAG,"WTF "+plateView.getBottom());
        if(false){
        }
        else{
            try{
                if (Math.abs(eOne.getY() - eTwo.getY()) > flingMaxOffPath)
                    return false;   //Too much of an arc in the fling.
                // right to left swipe
                if(eOne.getX() - eTwo.getX() > flingMinDistance && Math.abs(velocityX) > flingMinVelocity) {
                    tabHost.setAnimation(slideLeftIn);
                    tabHost.setAnimation(slideLeftOut);
                    tabHost.setCurrentTab((tabHost.getCurrentTab()+1)%3);
                }  else if (eTwo.getX() - eOne.getX() > flingMinDistance && Math.abs(velocityX) > flingMinVelocity) {
                    tabHost.setAnimation(slideRightIn);
                    tabHost.setAnimation(slideRightOut);
                    tabHost.setCurrentTab((tabHost.getCurrentTab()+2)%3);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

//This method alone keeps a touch in the weights from changing tabs, but won't register
//touches on ANY widget on any screen (like text views).
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event); 
}

//This method alone counts touches for swipes anywhere and everywhere.
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```